# Specific DateTime format for System.Text.Json ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I have a datetime input with format `dd/MM/yyyy` but the datetime is wrong when I debug to the controller

[image]

[image]

what I already try is make custom converter like this:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            var s = reader.GetString();
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt))
            {
                return dt;
            }
        }

        return reader.GetDateTime();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}

public class DateTimeNullableConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime?>
{
    public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var s = reader.GetString();
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt))
        {
            return dt;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

and register it to `Startup.cs` like this

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeNullableConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });
```

and still no result.

But if I change my computer date format to `dd/MM/yyyy` the code is work fine
[image]

is there anything wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share some JSON (as **text**) that reproduces the problem when deserialized -- i.e. a full [mcve]?